# Excess whitespace deleted bleeds into suggested edit markdown

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, diff, whitespace

As I was making [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8199629), I had noticed a lot of whitespace at the very end, which I then removed.  Now, when I look at the markdown of the edit suggestion, it kind of makes it look like I've tried to delete an entire line instead of the whitespace itself:

> [image]

I imagine this wouldn't actually affect reviews, especially if it gets compared to the rendered output, but it still looks a little weird.